# Accessing request.data breaks JSON parsing

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to lowercase a username in a login request before passing it to the login view provided by django-rest-framework-jwt. This code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def login(request):
    return obtain_jwt_token(request)
```

Works fine, though of course it effectively does nothing. Strangely, adding

```
print request.data
```

before the function returns causes a 400 error to be produced, with the message:

```
{"detail":"JSON parse error - No JSON object could be decoded"}
```

Why does simply reading the request object break the JSON parsing in this way?

Versions:

```
Django==1.9.1
djangorestframework==3.3.2
djangorestframework-jwt==1.7.2
```

As an added note: the print statement works fine, but breaks the JSON parsing. Printing `request.POST` has the same effect, however, printing `request.body` does not cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Because of reasons "Content-Type: application/json" header breaks DRF-JWT.
Just remove it.

Seen [here](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/157).